# Dúvida - View de sistema MVC

Tags: php, jquery, html, mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para uma contabilidade em PHP, MySQL, jQuery e css, o sistema é divido em setores, e cada setor possui uma aba de gráficos (plugin highcharts), que são gerados dinamicamente de acordo com os parâmetros passados.

Funciona da seguinte forma:

indexView() -> renderIndex() -> chama menu e opções ( suponhamos aqui que nós entramos no setor fiscal):

fiscalControll -> fiscalView() -> renderFiscal() -> chama as opções do fiscal e exibe a dashboard (agora suponhamos que clicamos na aba 'Gráficos'):

O sistema chama:

fiscalControll-> fiscalModel() -> get_charts_data_json_from_mysql($chart).

na sequencia o controll pega os dados do fiscalModel() e passa para o fiscalView() rederizar de alguma forma, ai está meu 'problema'.

Dúvida:

> Devo renderizar os gráficos diretamente pela função php, ou em uma pagina html separada com os locais dos gráficos?
>
> Obs: As duas formas funcionam, quase com o mesmo tempo de resposta, mas
>   qual seria o mais correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas parafraseando o conceito da `View`:

> View: responsável por todo o processamento necessário para a exibição, incluindo o processamento e renderização de objetos.

O `MVC` tem como foco principal a `View`. Logo, todas as demais camadas (`MC`) trabalham quase que exclusivamente para a `View`. Entretanto, o processamento/renderização é uma responsabilidade exclusiva da `View`.

Se algum tratamento de objetos é realizado por qualquer outra camada, com objetivo exclusivo de renderização, mova essa lógica para a `View`.

Os únicos contrapontos que posso adicionar, é quando o objeto é complexo demais e a `View` só utilizaria uma pequena parte dele. Nesse caso, o objeto pode ser tratado anteriormente. Entretanto, normalmente algum padrão, como `Proxy`/`LazyLoad`, faz esse trabalho por ti.

Como leitura complementar, sugiro os seguintes links:

https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/536201-mvc-p%C3%A1ginas-din%C3%A2micas/#comment-2141430

https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/557523-d%C3%BAvida-sobre-mvc-view/?do=findComment&comment=2224178